# Safely remove/uninstall android-sdk-linux

Tags: android, software-uninstall

I installed android-sdk-linux to run an Android program on Ubuntu. The installation was successful, but now I want to remove it. Since I am very new to Ubuntu, I don't know how to remove it safely.

I downloaded android-sdk-linux to my Downloads folder and I unzipped the file right there. I can locate the folder `android-sdk-linux`. What if I just delete this folder? Is it safe?

For the above installation I installed another program called *Open JDK java 7 runtime* which I found in the Ubuntu Software Center, and it is easy to remove it.

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the folder, that's all. `rm ~/Downloads/android-sdk-linux`

Answer (score 1):

Because you have only extracted the archive, you can simply remove the folder:

```
rm ~/Downloads/android-sdk-linux
```

Comment: HI, A.B., could you please tell me where I can find the folder in my home folder? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong, there is no additional folder in your home. I confused it.